# In R, how to know if a function printed warning messages to the console before return?

Tags: r

```r
func <- function() {
  warning("warning message")
  return(1)
}
```

1. `func` will print a warning before returning. But how can the fact that it print warning be detected by code?
2. How can the warning message be captured as a `character` value?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish that you need to do such a thing? You'd probably have to wrap the code that needs to catch warnings with `tryCatch()`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a call to the function with `tryCatch` to catch warnings. For example you can do it around the function itself

```
x <- tryCatch(func(), warning= function(w) {
  message(paste("a warning did occur:", conditionMessage(w)))
  return(0)
})
x
```

or you could do it inside the function

```
func <- function() {
  tryCatch({
    warning("warning message")  
  }, warning = function(w) {
    message(paste("a warning did occur:", conditionMessage(w)))
  })
  return(1)
}
```

Comment: If you want execution of the function to stop as soon as the warning occurs, use `tryCatch`. If you want execution to continue, use `withCallingHandlers`.